# how to check if hostname verification takes place during TLS/SSL handshake?

Tags: http, ssl, https, tls1.2

I have SSl socket connection between my computer and an external service. I had connected by just specifying an IP address so as per my understanding the name on certificate would be compared to the url specified while connecting and so the host name verification should fail. How can I confirm this through packet capture or otherwise? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I confirm this through packet capture ...

Certificate validation including hostname validation is done inside the client. Thus it cannot be observed on the network.

What can be observed on the network at least up to TLS 1.2 is the certificate send by the server. Thus you can do a packet capture, load it into Wireshark and check the leaf certificate there if it would match a proper hostname validation. If it does not, then you know that the client does not check the hostname properly. If it does match you still cannot be sure if it is checked by the client or not.

> ... or otherwise

Access the server by a different hostname with the client, for example by editing the hosts file and mapping some arbitrary name to the IP address, then accessing the server with this hostname and not the IP address. If it succeeds the client did not check the hostname. If it fails it might be due to the hostname check.

Comment: thank you. Tried the first method where I access server with IP and in the server certificate under the subjectAltName section I see 2 dns names (no ip addresses). So I guess this answers that there is no HNV taking place??  
second suggestion is also good but I cannot try in my particular case because I am not able to specify anything other than IP in my client (it is a simple socket connection which doesn't do dns resolves)

Comment: @applecodervinegar: *"So I guess this answers that there is no HNV taking place??"* - yes, likely no check. Note so that the client might expect a specific certificate by fingerprint of the certificate or publoc key (pinning), in which case hostname validation is not needed. You might check with something like mitmproxy if it will accept a different certificate or not.